# Navigation Bar Issues

Tags: html, css

I recently built a website but the nav bar is simply underdeveloped.

1. The dropdown menu I have doesn't really drop down, its sort of side to side.
2. Sometimes this doesn't align on ipads correctly.

Does anyone have advice on how to make my navbar stronger?

The HTML can be inspected on the website and here is the CSS.

```css
body {
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
    color: #00355A;
    text-align: center;
  
    
    /*border-style: solid;*/
    
}

.image1{
    width: 100%;

    
    
    height: auto;
    position: relative;

}
.image2{
    width: 100%;

    
    
    height: auto;
    position: relative;

}
.image3{
    width: 100%;

    
    
    height: auto;
    position: relative;

}
.image4{
    width: 100%;

    
    
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.image5{
    width: 100%;

    
    
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.ghostnav{
    display: none;
}
.ghostimage{
    display: none;
}
.ghosthome{
    display: none;
}
.ghostimage2{
    display: none;
}
.ghostoffer1{
    display: none;

}
.ghostoffer2{
    display: none;

}
.about-page{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    

}
.Aboutpageimg{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
/*
img {
    
    width: 100%;

    
    
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    
}
*/
/*

                                                                 Navigation Bar & Logo
*/

.container {
       max-width: 100%;
         
}

.wrapper ul{
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 20px;;
    display: inline-flex;
    list-style: none;
}
.wrapper ul li{
    
    margin-top: 21px;
    
    margin-right: 21px;
    margin-left: 21px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;

}
.wrapper ul li a{
    
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #00355A;
    
}
 .wrapper ul li a:hover{
    text-shadow: .3px .3px 1.7px rgb(95, 94, 94);

}
.sub-menu{
    display: none;
    
    
}
.wrapper ul li:hover .sub-menu{
    display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    right: 154px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    top: 3.5%;
   
   

}

.sub-menu a{
    padding-right: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    
    
}
    
header{
    
    display:flex; 
    font-size: 23px;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    
}


.logo{
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: auto;
    
}
/*
.about{
    color: grey;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.offerings{
    color: grey;
    text-decoration: none;
}

*/
/*

                                                                 Palos Verdes Backround & Constituents
                                                            
*/

.backround{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.backround2{
    position: relative;
    
}
.headlines {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    
    top: 10%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    
   
  
    
    text-shadow: .7px .7px 10px rgb(173, 172, 172);
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    
  
    
    font-size: 60px;
   
    
    

}

.headlines3 {
    width: 100%;

    position: absolute;
    top: 24%;
    left: 50%;

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";

    text-shadow: .7px .7px 10px rgb(173, 172, 172);    letter-spacing: 1px;
    

    
    
    font-size: 25px;
    

}


.headlines4 {
    width: 100%;

    position: absolute;
    top: 34%;
    left: 50%;
    
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";

    text-shadow: .7px .7px 10px rgb(173, 172, 172);    letter-spacing: 1px;
    

    
    
    font-size: 22px;
    

}
.buttonone{
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 20px 60px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color:white;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
.buttonone:link {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 22px;
   
    
    top: 48%;

    color: white;
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding: 20px 60px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    /*box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        text-shadow: .7px .7px 10px rgb(95, 94, 94);

    */

  }
.buttonone:hover {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 22px;
    
    top: 48%;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding: 20px 60px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-shadow: .7px .7px 10px rgb(95, 94, 94);

    

}



           /*
                                                                  Home Page Body
           */



.section1{
position: relative;
 /*
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
 /*
   border-style: dashed;
   */
    width: 100%;
    
    
}
.box1{
    
    
    text-align: center;
    right: 200px;

    

}
.experience{
    
    
    
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.473);
  font-size: 50px;
       
        width: 100%;
    
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
    text-shadow: .7px .7px 5px rgba(95, 94, 94, 0.644);
    border-top: 5px solid rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.397);
    border-radius: 20px;
    

    


}
.experience1{
    font-size: 35px;

    color : grey;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
    text-shadow: .7px .7px 10px rgba(95, 94, 94, 0.473);

}
.divider{
    border-top: 8px solid green;
}

.box1{
    border-style: solid;
}

.firstbody{
    border-style: solid;
}



/*

                                                                 Buttons @ Footers
*/
.buttontwo{
    width:18%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 3%;
    bottom: 1.5%;
    right: 22.5%;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid white;
    
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #00355A;

}   

.buttontwo:hover {

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1.5%;
    right: 22.5%;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid white;
  
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #00355a98;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-shadow: .7px .7px 10px rgb(95, 94, 94);

    

}

.about-page{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;

}
.buttontwoo{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    right: 22.5%;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding: 20px 60px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #00355A;

}   

.buttontwoo:hover {

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    right: 22.5%;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding: 20px 60px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #00355a98;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-shadow: .7px .7px 10px rgb(95, 94, 94);


}


.offerings-box{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;

}
.buttonthree{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    right: 22.5%;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding: 20px 60px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #00355A;

}   

.buttonthree:hover {

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    right: 22.5%;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding: 20px 60px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #00355a98;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-shadow: .7px .7px 10px rgb(95, 94, 94);}

    

    
    

.offerings2-box{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;

}
.buttonfour {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    right: 22.5%;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding: 20px 60px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #00355A;

}      


.buttonfour:hover {

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    right: 22.5%;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding: 20px 60px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #00355a98;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-shadow: .7px .7px 10px rgb(95, 94, 94);}
/*

                                                                 Contact Form
*/
.wrap{
    text-align: center;

}

.containertwo{
    
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    
    align-content: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    max-width: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    
    top: 20%;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    
}

.containertwo .title{
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.containertwo form .user-details{
    font-size: 30px;
    display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: space-between;
    
 

}

form .user-details .input-box {
    margin: 20px 0 12px 0;
    width: calc(100% / 2 - 20px);
}

.user-details .input-box input{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.user-details .input-box .FirstName{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.user-details .input-box .LastName{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.user-details .input-box .Email{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.user-details .input-box .Phone{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

form .product-details .product-selection{
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;

}
form .product-details .category{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
   
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 14px 0px;
}
.product-details .category label{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
   padding-right: 50px;
   
  
}
.product-details .category .dot{
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    background: #d9d9d9;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.product-details .category .product3{
    padding-right: 55px;
}


#dot-1:checked ~ .category label .one,
#dot-2:checked ~ .category label .two,
#dot-3:checked ~ .category label .three,
#dot-4:checked ~ .category label .four{
    border-color: #d9d9d9;
    background-color:#00355A; 
}

form input[type="radio"]{
    display: none;
}

form .button-contact{
    height: 45px;
    margin: 20px 0;

}
form .button-contact input{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100% ;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: #00355A;
    border-radius: 5px;
    
    
}

form .button-contact input:hover{
    background:#00355ade ;
}




/*

                                                                                     MEDIA QUERY
                                                                                     
*/


@media only screen and (max-width: 2560px){
    .wrapper ul li{
    
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-right: 21px;
        margin-left: 21px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    
    }
 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1570px){

    .headlines {
     
        font-size: 45px;
      
        
        
    
    }


.headlines3 {
  
    
    font-size: 20px;
    

}

.headlines4 {
   
    
    
    font-size: 20px;
    

}

    

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1527px){
    .buttontwo{
        
       
        
        font-size: 15px;
        
    }   
    
    .buttontwo:hover {
    
        
        font-size: px;
        
        
    
    }
    .buttontwoo{
        
        height: 5%;
        
        font-size: 10px;
        
    }   
    .buttontwoo:hover {
    
        
        font-size: 20px;
        
        
    
    }
    .buttonthree{
    right: 225px;    
    }   
    
    .buttonthree:hover {
        right: 225px;    
    
        
    
    }
    .buttonfour{
    
    right: 225px;    
    }   
        
        .buttonfour:hover {
        
            right: 225px;    
        
        }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1332px){
    .buttontwo{
        width:18%;
        height: 3%;    
    font-size: 10px;
    }   
    .buttontwoo{
        font-size: 10px;

    }   
    
    .buttontwoo:hover {
    
      
        font-size: 10px;
    
    
    }
    
  
    
    
    .headlines {  
        font-size: 30px;
    }


    .headlines3 {  
    font-size: 15px;
}

    .headlines4 { 
    font-size: 15px;
}
.buttonone{
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 13px, 20px, 15px, 20px;
}
.buttonone:link {
    
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 13px, 20px, 15px, 20px;   
   

  }
.buttonone:hover {
    
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 13px, 20px, 15px, 20px; 


}
.buttonthree{
    font-size: 10px;

}   

.buttonthree:hover {
    font-size: 10px;

    

}
.buttonfour{
    
font-size: 10px;
}   

.buttonfour:hover {

    font-size: 10px 

}


}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1155px){
    .buttontwo{    
        font-size: 10px;
        padding: 10px, 10px, 15px, 20px; 

    }   
    
    .buttontwo:hover {  
      font-size: 10px;
      right: 150px;
    }
    .buttontwoo{    
        font-size: 10px;
        padding: 10px, 10px, 15px, 20px; 
        right: 150px;

    }   
    .buttontwoo:hover {  
        font-size: 10px;
      }
  
    .buttonthree{    
        font-size: 10px;
        padding: 0px, 0px, 15px, 20px; 
        right: 150px;
    }   
    
    .buttonthree:hover {  
      font-size: 10px;
      right: 150px;

    }
    .buttonfour{    
        right: 150px;    

        font-size: 10px;
        padding: 0px, 0px, 15px, 20px; 
    }   
    
    .buttonfour:hover {  
        right: 150px;    

      font-size: 10px;
    }

    .headlines3 {
  
     font-size: 13px;
    }

    .headlines4 {  
    font-size: 13px;
    }

    .wrapper ul li{
        font-size: 13px;

        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-right: 21px;
        margin-left: 70px;
        
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    
    }
    /*
    .logo{
        max-width: 25%;
        
    }
*/
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 977px){

    
    .buttonone{
        font-size: 5px;
        padding: 10px 30px;    }
    .buttonone:link {
        
        font-size: 5px;
        padding: 10px 30px;    
      }
    .buttonone:hover {
        font-size: 5px;
        padding: 10px 30px;    }
    
        .buttontwoo{
            font-size: 5px;
            padding: 1px, 1px, 1px, 2px  ;
            right: 90px;          
             }
      
        .buttontwoo:hover {
            font-size: 5px;
            padding: 1px, 1px, 1px, 2px;
            right: 90px;          
        }
        
            .buttonthree{
                font-size: 5px;

                padding: 1px, 1px, 1px, 2px;
                right: 90px;

                   }
          
            .buttonthree:hover {
                right: 90px;

                    }
            
                .buttonfour{
                    font-size: 5px;
                    padding: 10px 30px;    }
              
                .buttonfour:hover {
                    font-size: 5px;
                    padding: 10px 30px;    }
                
    .headlines {  
        font-size: 20px;
    }


    .headlines3 {  
    font-size: 10px;
}

    .headlines4 { 
    font-size: 10px;
}
    .buttontwo{   font-size: 5px;   }   
    
    .buttontwo:hover {font-size: 5px; }
   
    
  
   
    .wrapper ul li{
        font-size: 8px;
        margin-left: 20px;
    
    }
    .logo{
        max-width: 30%;
        
    }

    
    
    
    .wrapper ul li:hover .sub-menu{
        display: inline;
       position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        right: 2px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        top: 3.5%;
        
    
    }
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 680px){
        
    .phonehomee{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
   .wrapper{
       display: none
   }
         
    .image2{
        display: none;
    }
    .image1{
        display: none;
    }  
    .image3{
        display: none;
    }
    .backround{
        display: none;

    }
    .backround2{
        display: none;

    }
   
    .dropbtn{
        background-color:#00355A ;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 100%;
        letter-spacing: 10px;
        font-size: 15px;
        

    

    }
    .ghostnav{
        
        display: block;
    }
    .dropdown-content{
        display: none;
        background-color: #00355A;
        width: 100%;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px #00355A;
        z-index: 1;
        
        letter-spacing: 10px;

       
    }
    .dropdown-content a{
        color: white;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
    .ghostnav:hover .dropdown-content{
        display: block;
    }
    .ghostimage{
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .ghosthome{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
   




    .Aboutpageimg{
        display: none;
    }

    .buttontwoo{
        display: none;

    }
    .ghostimage2{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }


    .image4{
        display: none;
    }

    .buttonthree{
        display: none;

    }
    .ghostoffer1{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    .image5{
        display: none;
    }
    .buttonfour{
        display: none;

    }
    .ghostoffer2{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    
    }
    .containertwo{
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    form .user-details .input-box {
margin-bottom: 15px;        
width: 100%;
    }
    
    
  }
```

Comment: Re: _"The HTML can be inspected on the website"_ Nope. Please add your HTML to your CSS above. Thanks.

Comment: Be specific what *"how to make my navbar stronger"* means

Comment: Also, please make your question's code runnable so we can see how it looks like and add a picture of the desired design